# How to use pydicom in jython

Tags: python, jython-2.7, pydicom

When I tried to import dicom in pydicom package I got error.
I performed the following steps.
Downloaded the pydicom-0.9.9.tar file,extracted and performed 'jython setup.py install' in cmd.But its not working.
Is this due to compatability of jython with python?
How to make pydicom is working in jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Jython on the bytecode files size. That is, Jython can’t compile the file if a module have huge bytecode size and unfortunately PyDicom have 2 such files. So, The work around is to split the files into junks and try installing.

This is a temporary work around and this issue has been resolved in Jython2.7.1 version. For now, try the following

- Split the “pydicom-0.9.8\dicom_dicom_dict.py” file into multiple files(4) files with 700 entries in a list.
- Split the “pydicom-0.9.8\dicom_private_dict.py” files into multiple files with 700 entries in each
- Search and change the usage of _dicom_dict.py contents in the pydicom package

  example: go to datadict.py and edit the following

  `from dicom._dicom_dict_1 import DicomDictionaryOne
   from dicom._dicom_dict_2 import DicomDictionaryTwo
   from dicom._dicom_dict_3 import DicomDictionaryThree
   from dicom._dicom_dict_4 import DicomDictionaryFour
   DicomDictionary.update(DicomDictionaryOne)
   DicomDictionary.update(DicomDictionaryTwo)
   DicomDictionary.update(DicomDictionaryThree)
   DicomDictionary.update(DicomDictionaryFour)`
- Search and change the usage of _private_dict.py contents in the pydicom package
  Install the package using setup.py